# InputStream.available() is always 0

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect to a server from my android app and get some JSON response. I am using `HttpUrlConnection`to ping the server. Server is running fine since I am getting the response on my browser. In the code below, the `inputStream.available()` always returns 0 and hence I cannot parse my data. Is there a way I could get the response ?

NOTE : The below method is called inside a separate thread (`AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`)

```
 private void pingServer(final String serverUrl) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {

            final URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);// milliseconds
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);// milliseconds
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            String resp = readIt(inputStream, inputStream.available());//resp is empty :(

        } catch (IOException e) {

        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

private String readIt(final InputStream stream,final int len) throws IOException {
        final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        final char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
```